# How to crop a selected picture in Outlook mail body with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

I need VBA Code for crop picture in outlook mail body
Does anyone have code please share with me

Answer (score 0):

After a 5 minute search on Google I found the following link https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/27768384/Outlook-macro-to-resize-picture-s.html

to summarise though this should help you (untested):

This macro will resize all pictures, including those in your signature (if any), in the currently open message to 75% of their height and width.

Follow these instructions to add the code to Outlook.

1. Start Outlook
2. Press ALT+F11 to open the Visual Basic Editor
3. If not already expanded, expand Microsoft Office Outlook Objects
4. If not already expanded, expand Modules
5. Select an existing module (e.g. Module1) by double-clicking on it or create a new module by right-clicking Modules and selecting Insert > Module.
6. Copy the code from the code snippet box and paste it into the right-hand pane of Outlook's VB Editor window
7. Click the diskette icon on the toolbar to save the changes
8. Close the VB Editor

Here's how to add a button to the QAT for running the macro with a single click.
Outlook 2010.  http://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/macrobutton.htm#qat

```
Sub ResizeAllPicsTo75Pct()
    Const wdInlineShapePicture = 3
    Dim olkMsg As Outlook.MailItem, wrdDoc As Object, wrdShp As Object
    Set olkMsg = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
    Set wrdDoc = olkMsg.GetInspector.WordEditor
    For Each wrdShp In wrdDoc.InlineShapes
        If wrdShp.Type = wdInlineShapePicture Then
            wrdShp.ScaleHeight = 75
            wrdShp.ScaleWidth = 75
        End If
    Next
    Set olkMsg = Nothing
    Set wrdDoc = Nothing
    Set wrdShp = Nothing
End Sub
```